# Was ist die deutsche Variante von "Textspeak"?

Tags: slang, abbreviation

Im englischsprachigen Netzjargon ist der Begriff "[textspeak](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/textspeak)" für abgekürzte Textbotschaften gebräuchlich.

Beispiel:

> `I h8 2 sA dat w'v 2 do r hmwrk 1st.` - *I hate to say that we have to do our homework first.* <sup>aus [Lingo2Word](http://www.lingo2word.com/translatetxt.php)</sup>

Man findet sogar eine ganze Reihe von Textspeak-Wörterbüchern.

Im Deutschen habe ich aber, obwohl auch wir solche Abkürzungen verwenden, keine Wörterbücher oder andere speziell auf diese Form abziehlenden Artikel gefunden. Einzig "[Netzjargon](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netzjargon)" ist ein sehr weiter Begriff, der wohl auch solche Abkürzungen beinhaltet.

Gibt es einen Begriff, der "Textspeak" im Deutschen abbildet? Gibt es vielleicht sogar ein Wörterbuch für deutsches "Textspeak"?

Comment: SMS-Sprache weil im Englischen es auch [SMS langauge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_language) heißt und weil immerhin die Limitierung der Zeichen einer SMS das ganze überhaupt erst so verbreitet hat.

Comment: bezieht diese Frage auch [Leetspeek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leetspeek) mit ein?

Comment: Leetspeek ist etwas anderes - wenn auch vielleicht mit einer gewissen Überlappung.

Comment: Geht es speziell um englische Abkürzungen mittels Ziffern und Buchstaben als Lauten in englischen Texten oder um die Analogie im Deutschen?

Comment: Das nennt man im Deutschen "Legasthenie"

Comment: Da habe ich m1e 2fel, ob solche 3sten Schreibweisen, bei denen sich mir die 10nägel hochklappen, im Deutschen sich nicht eher n8eilig auswirken, denn das tät 1em die ganze Kommunikation ver7.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Typo: `10ägel` schreibt sich nicht mit Doppel-n. ;-) SCNR Das Zeugs ist weder gut lesbar noch gut zu schreiben.

Answer (score 2):

"Hackersprache", "Textsprache", "Gamerjargon" oder halt das englische Wort "leetspeek" selbst. Es gibt dafür keinen wirklichen einheitlichen Begriff und jeder nennt es anders. Aber unter Jugendlichen ist "leetspeek" stark verbreitet. Erwachsene Menschen und Journalisten sprechen meistens vom "Netzjargon".

Comment: Zumindest den Vorschlag *Textsprache* halte ich für fragwürdig, da im Deutschen vermutlich meist nicht verständlich. Das "Wort" *SMS* hat sich weitgehend etabliert, während das im Englischen gebräuchliche Wort *text* (oder eben dessen deutsches Äquivalent *Text*) normalerweise nicht mit SMS/Kurznachrichten in Verbindung gebracht wird. Ohne Kontext würde ich *Textsprache* daher auch zunächst mal als ungewöhnliches Synonym für *Schriftsprache* auffassen, als an SMS zu denken, was stilistisch ungefähr das Gegenteil dessen sein dürfte, was gemeint ist.

Comment: Hackersprache und Gamerjargon sowie Leetspeek stehen für etwas anderes. Von dedizierten Abkürzungen wie "lol" abgesehen geht es dabei nicht um generelle Verkürzung der Sprache sondern um dedizierten Jargon der in bestimmten Bereichen üblich ist (z.B. unter Gamern). Dieser beinhaltet sicher auch Abkürzungen, aber entspricht nicht der generellen in SMS und anderen Kurznachrichten verwandten Abkürzungssprache. Bei vielen Nutzern letzterer wird man z.B. mit Leetspeek oder Hackersprache auf Unverständnis stoßen.

Answer (score 1):

Some people use [Netzjargon](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netzjargon) for that.
So I would argue that ***Netzjargon*** is a good translation of "textspeak"

Examples:
["[...]'Als Slashdot-Effekt oder Slashdotting wird im englischsprachigen Netzjargon eine durch die Leser von Massenmedien verursachte Überlastung eines Web-Servers bezeichnet.[...]"](http://www.heise-medien.de/artikel/Online-Angebote-1564151.html)

There are other similar usages of the term "Netzjargon" but it seems that it is a rather young word in German.

Comment: Bad answer! You already mentioned Netzjargon : (   But i would still argue that this is the best translation for Texstspeak

Comment: If there is nothing else to map... why not *"Netzjargon "* then ;)

Answer (score 0):

http://digitalewelt.freenet.de/handymobiles/handy/smskuerzel--das-steckt-hinter-den-akronymen_609386_1055376.html

Dort findest du eine Vielzahl deutscher sms-kürzel.
Ein paar wenige stehen auch dabei. Ob die deutschen Kürzel aber jedem so geläufig sind, ist fraglich.
Hoffe dennoch, dass dir der Link geholfen hat.

Comment: Die Frage zielt auf einen deutschen Begriff für "textspeak" ab; nicht jedoch auf die tausenden unsinnigen "Kürzel".

Comment: Warum fragt er dann nach einem solchen Wörterbuch? SMS-Jargon ist die eventuell korrekteste Übersetzung. Netzjargon deckt dieses aber bereits genügend ab.

Answer (score 0):

Wurde jetzt zwar ein paar mal erwähnt, aber noch nicht als Antwort, von daher:
Am ehesten trifft es **SMS-Jargon** oder **SMS-Sprache**. Wenn man es komplett Deutsch halten möchte gibt es auch noch "**Kurznachrichtensprache**" was zwar traditionell weniger verbreitet ist, aber dank der Zunahme an anderen (Kurz-)Nachrichtenanwendungen vermutlich in jüngerer Zeit an Verbreitung zunimmt.

Zur Abgrenzung treffen Leetspeak, Netz-Jargon, Hackersprache etc. alle nicht exakt das worauf die Frage abzielt. Hierbei handelt es sich jeweils um spezielle Jargons die in gewissen Kreisen benutzt werden. Dabei ist gerade nicht (immer) das Ziel sich möglichst kurz auszudrücken, und in der Regel besteht eine große Durchsetzung mit Begriffen die nur diesem Kreis geläufig sind. 
Textspeak dagegen bezieht sich auf die recht allgemeine Abkürzungssprache, die vielleicht in verschiedenen Gruppierungen mehr oder weniger stark angewandt wird, jedoch domänenunabhängig ist, deren Kernmerkmal also Abkürzungen geläufiger Worte/Sätze ist anstatt Fachbegriffe einer bestimmten Interessensgruppe.